# What are the sizes returned by `show collections`?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

**Edit**: This question is not about vanilla MongoDB's `show collections` but about `mongo-hacker`. See accepted answer and comments.

---

Using Mongo DB 3.2 + WiredTiger, `show collections` displays two sizes: s1 / s2.

```
show collections
coll_1               → 10.361MB / 1.289MB
coll_2               →  0.000MB / 0.004MB
coll_3               →  0.000MB / 0.016MB
coll_4               →  0.001MB / 0.031MB
```

My guess is these are:

- s1: total size of the documents in the database
- s2: size of the database on disk (documents + indexes) after compression

Is this correct? I couldn't find any reference in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#command-helpers).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using mongo-hacker? By default in MongoDB 3.2.11, `show collections` doesn't show any size information at all.

The size information provided by mongo-hacker is obtained from the output of `db.collection.stats().size` which shows you the total uncompressed size of the collection (*without* indexes), and `db.collection.stats().storageSize` which shows you the physical storage size. If you enable compression in WiredTiger, the `storageSize` will typically be smaller than `size`.

You can find the relevant source code in here: https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker/blob/0.0.13/hacks/show.js#L57-L72

Comment: So that would be what I defined as "total size of the documents" and "size on disk (documents + indexes)". Thanks for the source code. It looks pretty much like this. However, I never heard about mongo-hacker. I'm using MongoDB Debian packages from Mongo repository. Don't we have the same default Mongo?

Comment: OK, I get it. I copied `.mongorc.js` from my colleague to get colorized shell and it happens to include mongo-hacker stuff. I don't remember installing mongo-hacker specifically but apparently it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, mongo-hacker works by creating a .mongorc.js in your home directory. I guess you can "accidentally" use mongo-hacker if you copied someone's .mongorc.js file. Note that you can run mongo shell with `mongo --norc` to ignore the rc file.

Comment: I do mean to use this .rc file. I just copied it without checking what was inside (it comes from a "trusted zone"...) and I thought it was mostly about colours, I didn't think it would affect those outputs. But it's nice and I'm glad it does. BTW, the reason I don't remember installing mongo-hacker is that my colleague wanted to avoid using npm (we're from Python world, JS is hostile territory) so he basically concatenated mongo-hacker files into a single .rc file. Might not be best practice, but that's another story... Thanks anyway for sorting this out.

Comment: Glad to help. Actually you don't need npm to use mongo-hacker. It's basically a github repo, and you install it using the `make install` command, which essentially does what you described (concat assorted files into one rc file). Here's a link to the site: http://tylerbrock.github.io/mongo-hacker/, which also lists additional features that comes by default with it. I highly recommend it, since you can add/remove "hacks" as you see fit.

Comment: Right. I'll do that, it's much better. Thanks again.

Comment: I use a tiny function on my servers, can't use vanilla console any more...

https://github.com/thapakazi/kutto_kodalo/blob/gumantae/shellrc.d/utils.sh#L96-L102

Answer (score 39):

You can use the below query to get the size of each collections:

```
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames(),
  stats = [];
collectionNames.forEach(function (n) {
  stats.push(db[n].stats());
});
for (var c in stats) {
  // skip views
  if (!stats[c]["ns"]) continue;
  print(stats[c]["ns"].padEnd(40) + ": " + (''+stats[c]["size"]).padEnd(12) + " (" + (stats[c]["storageSize"] / 1073741824).toFixed(3).padStart(8) + "GB)");
}
```

Example putout:

```
cod-prod-db.orders: 35179407 (0.012GB)
cod-prod-db.system.profile: 4323 (0.000GB)
cod-prod-db.users: 21044037 (0.015GB)
```

Comment: for sizes in GB use `print(stats[c]['ns'] + ": " + stats[c]['size'] + " (" + stats[c]['storageSize']/1073741824.0 + "GB)")`

Comment: use `1048576` instead of `1073741824` to get in MB

Answer (score 9):

Very similar to @kalaivani's answer, I just refactored it for easier (for me) understanding and also printing in GB

```
// Get collection names
var collectionNames = db.getCollectionNames()
var col_stats = [];

// Get stats for every collections
collectionNames.forEach(function (n) { 
    col_stats.push(db.getCollection(n).stats());
});

// Print
for (var item of col_stats) {
    print(`${item['ns']} | size: ${item['size']} 
(${(item['size']/1073741824).toFixed(2)} GB) | storageSize: ${item['storageSize']} 
(${(item['storageSize']/1073741824).toFixed(2)} GB)`);
}
```